# reading csv file into access database

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I want to read a csv file into an  access database , here is my code :

```
Private Sub load_csv()
    Dim ConnectionString As String
    ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & input_file & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=Yes"""
    Dim TextConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)
    TextConnection.Open()
    Dim da As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter _
   ("SELECT * INTO [MS Access;Database=" & current_db & "].[Rapoarte] FROM [" & input_file & "]", TextConnection)
End Sub
```

When i run it i get an error :

> ```
> 'C:\Documents and Settings\username\Desktop\test.csv'
> ```
>
> is not a valid path.  Make sure that
>   the path name is spelled correctly and
>   that you are connected to the server
>   on which the file resides.

The strange thing is that the file really is there, so what else could go wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind,

I found what I was doing wrong.

Instead of providing the file path i was giving it the file name.
For reference it should look like this.

```
Private Sub load_csv()
        Dim ConnectionString As String
        ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & file_path & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=Yes"""
        Dim TextConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)
        TextConnection.Open()
        Dim da As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter _
       ("SELECT * INTO [MS Access;Database=" & current_db & "].[Rapoarte] FROM [" & input_file & "]", TextConnection)
    End Sub
```